# IQueryable vs IEnumerable - why the former doesn't support closure?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, closures, ienumerable, iqueryable

This code:

```
var query = from category in db.GlobalCategories // <- IQueryable DB call.
            let button = new XElement("Button").Attr("Name", category.Name)
            select button;

query.ToArray();
```

produces a set of values - **which are all the same** - equal to the last database record.

When I change the code, adding `AsAnumerable()`:

```
// Forced IEnumerable.

var query = from category in db.GlobalCategories.AsEnumerable()
            let button = new XElement("Button").Attr("Name", category.Name)
            select button;

query.ToArray();
```

the set is as expected - **each value is unique** and matches the database record.

`.Attr()` is an extension method for fluent setting XML attributes for `XElement`:

```
public static XElement Attr(this XElement x, string key, object value)
{
    x.SetAttributeValue(key, value);
    return x;
}
```

If the `.Attr()` **is not use**d, then **both the cases work as expected**.

Why is it so? How can it be fixed so that it would not require forced IEnumerable?
Why the `category` is not captured in the first case and is captured in the second?

Comment: The variable db.GlobalCategories is against a datatable which is not enumberable.  So adding AsEnumerable() gets the rows of the datatable which are enumerable.  You do not need IEnumerable.  You are returning a List<DataRow> or DataRow[] from the query.

Comment: IQueryable represents a *query*. In this case, a SQL query. You *can't* use `XElement` in such a query. EF would throw an error in this case. Linq-to-SQL will generate a query if it can, load the results and treat it as IEnumerable. Whatever you want to do , just don't use LINQ-to-SQL. If you want to check what L2S executed, use a profiler to see the actual SQL query

Comment: Another *serious* problem is that LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. It's a *query* language that sits on top of an *ORM*. ORM means Object-Relational *Mapping*, not transformation. The mappings should be defined in the ORM's configuration, not the query code. If you can't specify them there, eg if you need to perform complex transformations, you should use a view to hide the transformations

Comment: What dose this have to do with closures?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the Linq-to-Sql is designed to execute on SQL server for as much as it can - it has special functions conversions, like `string.Contains()` => `LIKE()` etc, so it is absolutely OK to use non-convertible methods, like extension or custom type custructors, as long as the SQL query doesn't depend on them (for instance, there is no comparsion with a method-generated value, whereas the method accepts a db entity parameter).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so there is no need to use Views, or plain SQL code, the usage of Linq-to-Sql is to be flexible and agile, and my code is works fine as long as I don't use the extension method. Which is weird.

Comment: @AgentFire it's not OK at all, because it ends up loading a lot more data than you thought, without warning. It's also *NO LONGER* being developed. It was only used as an example of what LINQ could do. Your code doesn't work fine if it ends up loading 100 rows instead of 1. It's not agile and flexible either, it's random

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos why should it load 1? My goal is to load all of them, actually. Did you read the question, or you are mere an Linq-to-Sql hater?

Comment: It looks like only one XElement object is created with your first example, but if you reference category inside the XElement constructor (eg `let button = new XElement(category).Attr("Name", category.Name)` then it creates multiple objects. (So it looks like the extension method isn't really to blame).

Comment: No, I've used it since it came out. That's why I told you to check the actual query. What is the actual data returned?

Comment: @sgmoore, indeed, I have independently came to the same result - if I use the `category` somwhere in the constructor (I have added `"Button" + category.Name.Substring(0, 0)` instead of just `"Button"` and it worked fine. But why! :) if the extension method is used explicitly, the behaviour is unaffected.

Comment: If the constructor for XElement does **not** depend on category, it would look like the XElement constructor is moved **outside** the loop and created once  **before** the database access takes place.If you replace XElement with a subclass that takes a parameter but does not use it (and let your extension method do the real work) it will work correctly if the parameter passed depends on category.